# Firebug debugging issues

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, firebug

I am trying to debug a MVC app that uses JQuery.

Firstly I have version 1.3.3 of Firebug and I have set
the Break on All Errors option and have added a deliberate
error but it is not breaking on the error.

Secondly after I have activated something that has a javascript
function and put breakpoint in and then let it continue, it then
no longer hit s that breakpoint if I reactivate the function.

Thirdly can you put watch expressions in for JQuery statments
because I have, and it says undefined in watch list window.

Malcolm

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/firebug

Comment: Did you post this twice? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788295/referencing-jquery-statements-and-debugging][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788295/referencing-jquery-statements-and-debugging

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, one of the newer patches of Firefox broke Firebug's javascript debugging.  You can try upgrading to the 1.4 alpha (http://getfirebug.com/) but that causes other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to note, is that sometimes it lets you put a breakpoint on any given line, but from my experience its really only when the line number turns green that you can rely on that breakpoint working.

I was disabling and re-enabling firebug back and forth when to fix it at one point, but I often had to kill the firefox.exe process.  Anyway, when the line numbers are green you're good to debug once before having to disable and re-enable again (at least that was my browser's behavior).