# Referencing Jquery statements and debugging

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, debugging

VS2008.

I have an MVC app and I dynamically rendering html
for a control I am building.

I have written some javascript and put in a .js file.

My master page has a refernce to my jquery js file.

A user control then calls my code to render html.

My js file uses JQuery.

When i debug i am getting an "undefined" error when printing
the statement in Immediate Window.

Is this because my js file does not reference the Jquery JS file?

If so how do I reference it??

Malcolm

Comment: I'm not sure what "Immediate Window" is. I would suggest using Firefox and Firebug to get a more specific idea of what exactly is undefined.

Comment: Malcolm, You can't debug javascript in Visual Studio. Use Firebug like I mentioned in my answer. Visual Studio is for debugging server side code.

Comment: BS of course you can. And I have tried Firebug....same fustration....cant get it to work either...want to teach me how to use it????

Answer (score 0):

If you don't reference jQuery then yeah.

Make sure you include it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dhtml/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Immediate window is for server side code.

Grab Firebug for firefox add-on for javascript output and check out the console.log functionality

jQuery without Firebug is painful

Comment: *Immediate window is for server side code.* - Total bollocks. The immediate window will happily debug Javascript and jQuery. In fact it's one of the nicest ways to learn / play with / workout selectors.

Comment: visual studio 2010 may allow you to, but not 2008, thanks for being almost 2 years late to the conversation flesh

Comment: Not true either.  I can use VS2008 to debug javascript and jQeury. I am running SP1 though, not sure if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Malcom,

Make sure that your jquery reference is resolving -- you can use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), or your can just test the url out while the web server's up.  I definitely agree that having [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) around when doing JS/UI development is a must!

Look for the script reference when you load your page...  You may copy the url out and test by pasting in the browser... for example, if you view source on your web site's url (http://localhost:1234/) and see:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

enter http://localhost:1234/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js in your browser and see whether you receive the JS content (or are prompted to download).

Hope this helps.

Seth

Comment: Yes the jquery js and my js are referenced....but when i debug my js should that file have an explcit reference to the jquery in it, do you understand my meaning???

Comment: If you've referenced JQuery before your js file, you shouldn't explicitly need to reference it from within.